# how to chunk multiminsional array by keys

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have a `xml` file that I am trying to turn into an array but I want the keys to be the indexes if they're an array else to just add the key to the current array, or split each array into a global variable. An example is below. However from this I can only flatten the array, I have more extensive code available at: https://github.com/mithereal/xml-to-struct-go

```
  class RecursiveRealArrayIterator extends RecursiveArrayIterator
  {
   public function hasChildren()
   {
        $current = $this->current();
        return is_array( $current ) || $current instanceof Traversable;
   }
   }

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <!-- Call-specific Input Fields -->
  <CreateTimeFrom> dateTime </CreateTimeFrom>
  <CreateTimeTo> dateTime </CreateTimeTo>
  <IncludeFinalValueFee> boolean </IncludeFinalValueFee>
  <ListingType> ListingTypeCodeType </ListingType>
  <ModTimeFrom> dateTime </ModTimeFrom>
  <ModTimeTo> dateTime </ModTimeTo>
  <NumberOfDays> int </NumberOfDays>
  <OrderIDArray> OrderIDArrayType
    <OrderID> OrderIDType (string) </OrderID>
    <!-- ... more OrderID values allowed here ... -->
  </OrderIDArray>
  <OrderRole> TradingRoleCodeType </OrderRole>
  <OrderStatus> OrderStatusCodeType </OrderStatus>
  <Pagination> PaginationType
    <EntriesPerPage> int </EntriesPerPage>
    <PageNumber> int </PageNumber>
  </Pagination>
  <SortingOrder> SortOrderCodeType </SortingOrder>
  <!-- Standard Input Fields -->
  <DetailLevel> DetailLevelCodeType </DetailLevel>
  <!-- ... more DetailLevel values allowed here ... -->
  <ErrorLanguage> string </ErrorLanguage>
  <MessageID> string </MessageID>
  <OutputSelector> string </OutputSelector>
  <!-- ... more OutputSelector values allowed here ... -->
  <Version> string </Version>
  <WarningLevel> WarningLevelCodeType </WarningLevel>
</GetOrdersRequest>'

$flat = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr)); return iterator_to_array($it, true);

function XMLToArray($xml)
    {
        $return = false;

        if ($xml instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
            $children = $xml->children();
            $return = false;

            foreach ($children as $element => $value) {
                if ($value instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
                    $values = (array)$value->children();

                    if (count($values) > 0) {
                        $return[$element] = $this->XMLToArray($value);
                    } else {
                        if (!isset($return[$element])) {
                            $return[$element] = (string)$value;
                        } else {
                            if (!is_array($return[$element])) {
                                $return[$element] = array($return[$element], (string)$value);
                            } else {
                                $return[$element][] = (string)$value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return $return;

    }

class  object(){
var properties
 function newproperty($array, $i)
{

    $this->properties[$i] = $array;

    if (is_array($array)) {
        $i++;
        $this->newproperty($array,$i);

    }


return $array;
}

 function make($array)
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $dim) {
        $this->newproperty($dim, $i);
        $i++;
    }
    return $this->properties;
}
}
$structs = obj::make($arr)
```

Comment: Can you post your array structure with expected output

Comment: if you don't have attributes then use simplexml library

Comment: they should be seperate arrays like something like this ... GetOrdersRequest[];GetOrdersRequest[CreateTimeFrom]; GetOrdersRequest[CreateTimeTo]; GetOrdersRequest[IncludeFinalValueFee]; GetOrdersRequest[ListingType]; GetOrdersRequest[WarningLevel]; ... OrderIDArray[OrderID]; .. Pagination[EntriesPerPage];

Comment: the goal is to turn the xml document into a c-like struct, so i need each array element that has a key that is also an array to be a seperate structure.

Comment: another way to  say this is how to return all inclusive arrays as unique single diminsion arrays

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get the result like below

```
<?php 

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <!-- Call-specific Input Fields -->
  <CreateTimeFrom> dateTime </CreateTimeFrom>
  <CreateTimeTo> dateTime </CreateTimeTo>
  <IncludeFinalValueFee> boolean </IncludeFinalValueFee>
  <ListingType> ListingTypeCodeType </ListingType>
  <ModTimeFrom> dateTime </ModTimeFrom>
  <ModTimeTo> dateTime </ModTimeTo>
  <NumberOfDays> int </NumberOfDays>
  <OrderIDArray> OrderIDArrayType
    <OrderID> OrderIDType (string) </OrderID>
    <!-- ... more OrderID values allowed here ... -->
  </OrderIDArray>
  <OrderRole> TradingRoleCodeType </OrderRole>
  <OrderStatus> OrderStatusCodeType </OrderStatus>
  <Pagination> PaginationType
    <EntriesPerPage> int </EntriesPerPage>
    <PageNumber> int </PageNumber>
  </Pagination>
  <SortingOrder> SortOrderCodeType </SortingOrder>
  <!-- Standard Input Fields -->
  <DetailLevel> DetailLevelCodeType </DetailLevel>
  <!-- ... more DetailLevel values allowed here ... -->
  <ErrorLanguage> string </ErrorLanguage>
  <MessageID> string </MessageID>
  <OutputSelector> string </OutputSelector>
  <!-- ... more OutputSelector values allowed here ... -->
  <Version> string </Version>
  <WarningLevel> WarningLevelCodeType </WarningLevel>
</GetOrdersRequest>';

//create xml object
$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

//object to array
$array = get_object_vars($obj);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: that doesnt work, it does not return correctly, it does output the first level correctly, then theres arrays i have to go into with loop logic, i want all the arrays in the collection/set to be put on 1 diminsion/plane i tried using tail recursion but it just blew up i added to the question

Comment: there is no otherway from my side you have to use loop only. This is not proper xml too  <Pagination> PaginationType
    <EntriesPerPage> int </EntriesPerPage>
    <PageNumber> int </PageNumber>
  </Pagination>  these details should be in attributes (PaginationType) or in tags.

Comment: you can directly use the object `$obj->CreateTimeFrom` until needs an array. only specific places you can use the loop